# How to load external script with optimized require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We use require.js to manage library dependencies. During development it loads our code from individual JS files, while the production build is optimized into a single JS file.

I'm now trying to load external JS libraries dynamically. I'm trying to add new libraries with `require.config` and then use them:

```
require.config({paths:{ "d3":"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min" }})
require(['d3'], function(d3) { console.log("Works!") })
```

It works as expected in the non-optimized build. However, in the optimized build it produces an error:

```
Uncaught Error: undefined missing d3
```

It seems that the optimized require somehow different from the non-optimized library. How can I get dynamic configuration and loading working in the optimized build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our build scripts replaced require.js with [almond](https://github.com/requirejs/almond) in the production build. It's meant as a require.js replacement for single-file builds which does not include external file loading support.

I wish the almond error messages were a bit more verbose, it took me hours to track that one down.